# highchart column chart negative stack labels overlap with axis labels

Tags: highcharts, column-chart

When there are negative stack labels for a column chart, they overlap with axis labels for considerably large values.

Here's a fiddle to recreate the problem.
[https://jsfiddle.net/adityapachpor/0fekodq3/2/]

The value "-450" overlaps with axis label here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `dataLabels` inside the plot area, you need to leave the default `justify` setting for `dataLabels.overflow` option.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hjr1wuyt/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.overflow